# ImportError: cannot import name 'UserSerializer' from 'user.serializers'

Tags: python, django, importerror

I started a project in django and I am having problems with imports. I think the problem is caused by cyclical imports. I have changed the code in many ways, but I cannot solve it.

The error:

```sh
  File "/home/Workspace/vesta/vesta/urls.py", line 8, in <module>
    from user.api import UserModelViewSet
  File "/home/Workspace/vesta/user/api.py", line 8, in <module>
    from user.serializers import UserSerializer
  File "/home/Workspace/vesta/user/serializers.py", line 5, in <module>
    from core.serializers import (UUIDSerializer)
  File "/mhome/Workspace/vesta/core/serializers.py", line 2, in <module>
    from user.serializers import UserSerializer
ImportError: cannot import name 'UserSerializer' from 'user.serializers' (/home/Workspace/vesta/user/serializers.py)
```

And the code:

**vesta/vesta/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.urls import include, re_path
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (TokenObtainPairView, TokenRefreshView, TokenVerifyView)

from core.api.schemas.schema_view import schema_view
from user.api import UserModelViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'user', UserModelViewSet, basename='user')

urlpatterns = [
    # API documentation and playground
    re_path(r'^api-doc/$', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='api-doc'),
    re_path(r'^api-playground(?P<format>\.json|\.yaml)$', schema_view.without_ui(cache_timeout=0),
            name='api-playground-json'),
    re_path(r'^api-playground/$', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='api-playground-ui'),

    # Admin
    re_path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # Authentication token
    re_path(r'auth/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    re_path(r'auth/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    re_path(r'auth/token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_verify'),

    # API
    re_path(r'', include(router.urls))
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

**vesta/user/api.py**

```py
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema
from rest_framework import mixins

from core.api.parameters import query_parameter
from core.viewsets import BaseModelViewSet
from user.models import User
from user.serializers import UserSerializer


@method_decorator(name='retrieve', decorator=swagger_auto_schema(manual_parameters=[query_parameter]))
class UserModelViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                       BaseModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'email'
    lookup_value_regex = r'[\w.@+-]+'

    action_serializers = {
        'retrieve': UserSerializer
    }

    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)
```

**vesta/user/serializers.py**

```py
from django_restql.mixins import DynamicFieldsMixin
from rest_framework import serializers

from core.serializers import ModificationSerializer
from core.serializers import (UUIDSerializer)
from group.serializers import GroupSerializer
from user.models import User


class UserSerializer(DynamicFieldsMixin, serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer, UUIDSerializer,
                     ModificationSerializer):
    groups = GroupSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta(UUIDSerializer.Meta, ModificationSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = UUIDSerializer.Meta.fields + ModificationSerializer.Meta.fields + ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name',
                                                                                    'groups']
```

**vesta/core/serializers.py**

```py
from rest_framework.serializers import BaseSerializer
from user.serializers import UserSerializer


class UUIDSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['uuid']


class ModificationSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    modified_by = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        fields = ['modified_at', 'modified_by']
```

**Tree**

```sh
vesta
├── core
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── parameters
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── query_parameter.py
│   │   └── schemas
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       └── schema_view.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── creation_model.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── modification_model.py
│   │   └── uuid_model.py
│   ├── serializers.py  # <---------------------- Here (UseSerializer)
│   └── viewsets
│       ├── base_model_view_set.py
│       └── __init__.py
├── group
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── group_admin.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── group_model.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── serializers
│       ├── group_serializer.py
│       └── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── user
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── user_admin.py
│   ├── api.py  # <---------------------- Here (UseSerializer)
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── managers
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── user_manager.py
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── user_model.py
│   └── serializers.py
└── vesta
    ├── asgi.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings
    │   ├── base.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── local.py
    │   └── third_party
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── rest_framework.py
    │       └── swagger.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

I think that the problem is between the file **vesta/user/api.py** and **vesta/core/serializers.py**.

How can i solve that?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can preface a dot before package imports to go up relative directories for imports. Example:

```
├── example.py
└── vesta
    ├── core
    │   └── serializers.py
    └── user
        └── serializers.py
```

vesta/user/serializers.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

class UserSerializer:

    @staticmethod
    def example():
        print('working')
```

vesta/core/serializers.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from ..user.serializers import UserSerializer


UserSerializer.example()
```

example.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import vesta.core.serializers
```

output

```
$ python example.py
working
```

Depending on how you have your environment setup, this won't always work, but if you have everything setup in a package and don't try to access scripts outside the package without also putting them in a module, this way works well in my experience.

Comment: Adding a point, the error is `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`. I have added the project structure.

Comment: It seems your project structure is laid out out more as module1, module2, module3 in the same, top level directory. For the relative path imports to work, you need to have everything within the same top level module, so that would mean putting core, vesta, etc. into one package, called say containment and then you would be able to do relative imports. While they're separate like this, another way of solving this would be to install them all as separate packages, ie one for vesta one for core, etc, and then standard imports would work. Youll need to choose the best organization for your project